# Changes made using wfs-t and GeoExt don't get saved to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, geoext, wfs-t

I'm using GeoExt to display and edit a vector layer from GeoServer (running with Apache Tomcat) but if I modify the shape of an existing polygon (or create a new one but I'm trying not to leap ahead of myself) the change doesn't get written back to PostGIS through GeoServer. I'm using code obtained from a tutorial at http://workshops.opengeo.org/geoext/wfs/wfst.html. I see a few people have had problems with the same code but can't find any solutions that solve my problem.

The code for the save button action:

```
    handler: function() {
  app.featureGrid.store.protocol.commit(
   vectorLayer.features, {
    callback: function() {
        var layers = app.mapPanel.map.layers;
        for (var i=layers.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
          layers[i].redraw(true);
        }
        app.featureGrid.store.reload();
    }
  });
}
```

My map layers get redrawn and the polygon changes persist but if I reload the page, the original shape is back. There is no error in Chrome developer tools but if i look in the GeoServer log file, I get:

```
2012-05-10 14:51:31,311 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2012-05-10 14:51:31,321 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.wfs.WFSTransactionException: Feature type 'dev_apps' is not available: 
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.execute(Transaction.java:222)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.transaction(Transaction.java:108)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.DefaultWebFeatureService.transaction
   (DefaultWebFeatureService.java:162)
```

I'd really appreciate some help as I don't know where to look anymore!

Comment: what is you GeoServer version ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your server believes that you have asked for a feature type named  'dev_apps'. You might want to check the namespace of your workspace.